# Are embedded points where the nonreducedness is?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

I know that if Spec $A$ is reduced, then there are no embedded points. I was wondering, if I know that $p$ is an embedded point of some Spec $B$, does that imply $B_{p}$ is non-reduced? Thanks!

Comment: It seems worth commenting that embedded points are not the only sources of nonreducedness. For example, $k[x,y] / f^2$ for an irreducible polynomial $f$ has only one associated (minimal) prime ideal $(f)$, which is not embedded, but its local ring is nonreduced. (This is called being "generically nonreduced".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If we have $p \in \operatorname{Ass} B$, we have $pB_p \in \operatorname{Ass} B_p$. So $pB_p = Ann(x)$. Clearly $0 \neq x$ is no unit because $p \neq 0$ (since it was an embedded prime, in particular not a minimal prime). We obtain $x \in pB_p$, hence $x^2=0$.